# “Spent time for training” vs. “spent time on training” vs. “spent time on training of ”

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

- We’ve spent X hours ?*on training of* the new employee.
- We’ve spent X hours ?*on training* the new employee.
- We’ve spent X hours ?*for training* the new employee.

Are these interchangeable?

Comment: The first two are, but I wouldn't use the third

Comment: The first is grammatically incorrect. It should be something like "We've spent X hours **on the training of** the new employee."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With "spend," I normally follow these patterns:

```
spend something + on + Noun

spend something + V+ing
```

So, I would correct all your sentences this way:

> We've spent X hours on **the** training of the new employee.
>
> We've spent X hours **training** the new employee.

I wouldn't use "*for*."

Answer (score 6):

No, and you might as well simply say:

> We've spent x hours training the new employee.